# Getting the good row in a MySQL GROUP BY query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySql table named 'comments' :

```
id | date       | movie_id | comment_value
1    2011/11/05   10         comment_value_1
2    2012/01/10   10         comment_value_2
3    2011/10/10   15         comment_value_3
4    2011/11/20   15         comment_value_4
5    2011/12/10   30         comment_value_5
```

And i try to have the most recent comment for each movie with the query :

```
SELECT MAX(date),id,date,movie_id,comment_value FROM comments GROUP BY movie_id
```

The MAX(date) return the most recent date, but the row associated (movie_id,id,comment_value,date) did not match. It returns the value of the first comment of the movie, like this :

```
MAX(date)  | id | date       | movie_id | comment_value
2012/01/10   1    2011/11/05   10         comment_value_1
2011/11/20   3    2011/10/10   15         comment_value_3
2011/12/10   5    2011/12/10   30         comment_value_5
```

So, my question is : how can i have the most recent comment for each movie, in only one query ( i'm actually using a second query to get the good comment)

Comment: Do you only have one comment per movie per date? If there is more than one comment for a movie on the same date, how will ties be broken, or would you want them all? You might want to consider full DATETIME column instead of DATE column.

Comment: Yes, i only have one comment per movie per date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using two queries isn't so bad. Otherwise you can do something like

```
SELECT id, date, movie_id, comment_value FROM comments c JOIN
(SELECT movie_id, MAX(date) date FROM comments GROUP BY movie_id) x
ON x.movie_id=c.movie_id AND x.date=c.date GROUP BY movie_id;
```

Comment: Is last group by is necessary?

Comment: @jules, be sure to check out tpolyak's better answer.

Comment: @ThitLwinOo i confirm, it works whitout last group by. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT c1.* 
FROM comments c1 
LEFT JOIN comments c2 ON (c1.movie_id = c2.movie_id AND c1.date < c2.date)
WHERE c2.id IS NULL
```

Because of the join condition it will be able to join only the rows which don't contain the maximum date value, so filtering the rows with c2.id IS NULL gives you rows with maximum values.

Comment: +1 This is the method recommended by the book [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns), which is much easier to optimize than using a subquery.

Comment: I understand the idea, but when i execute the query, my rows are not grouped by movie_id.

Comment: You would still have to add `GROUP BY movie_id` if that's what you want.

Comment: I figured out why it's not working. Just replace `c1.id = c2.id` by `c1.movie_id = c2.movie_id` AND `c2.id IS NULL` by `c2.movie_id IS NULL`. Query looks to be faster. Thank you

Comment: @MarcusAdams The book SQL Antipatterns looks good. I think i'm going to buy it right now :)

Comment: yes, movie_id is the correct column to use, thank you for editing

Answer (score 0):

```
create table comments (id int,movie_dt datetime,movie_id int,comment_value nvarchar(100))

insert into comments values (1,'2011/11/05',10,'comment_value_1')
insert into comments values (2,'2012/01/10',10,'comment_value_2')
insert into comments values (3,'2011/10/10',15,'comment_value_3')
insert into comments values (4,'2011/11/20',15,'comment_value_4')
insert into comments values (5,'2011/12/10',30,'comment_value_5')

select a.id, m.movie_dt, m.movie_id,a.comment_value
from comments a
inner join 
(
    SELECT MAX(movie_dt) movie_dt,movie_id
    FROM comments 
    GROUP BY movie_id
) m on (a.movie_dt = m.movie_dt and a.movie_id = m.movie_id)
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible to use a DATETIME field instead of just DATE? That would make the query a lot easier plus give better reporting capabilities. You can always aggregate the DATETIME field down to something more specific if needed.

Comment: Yes, it possible to use DATETIME. But i don't really understand what difference it makes. Can you explain more ?

Comment: DATETIME includes the time (down to the millisecond). So when doing SELECT MAX(date) from comments you will always get the most recent comment.